# Why calling NextValue() on PerformanceCounter object throw error?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, perfmon

Why the following code throws the error `Instance 'taskmgr' does not exist in the specified Category.` when I don't pass params in ctor

```
var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";            
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "taskmgr";
cpuCounter.NextValue();
```

But, when I do the same by passing params in ctor no error is raised.

```
var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
    "Processor",
    "% Processor Time",
    "taskmgr");
cpuCounter.NextValue();
```

**UPDATED:**
I've tried on every process name, not only "taskmgr" and the result is the same!

What is the problem?

Comment: actually it's giving the same error for me in both cases

Comment: Are you sure taskmgr was actually running when you executed both chunks of code?

Comment: yes. I've double checked. It happens on every process name I put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `taskmgr` instance available for the `Processor` category because `Processor` is about your CPUs...

You probably meant `Process`, which works as expected:

```
var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";            
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "taskmgr";
cpuCounter.NextValue();
```

Comment: You are right! This fixed the problem. But still, for `CategoryName="Processor"` why it only worked when I passed params in ctor?

Comment: @theateist Could you provide a reproducible example? I've just tested Processor with 0 as instance (i.e. the first core of your machine), it works in both cases for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are providing the correct value for `CategoryName`/`InstanceName`? From the [documentation for InstanceName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.instancename.aspx) it looks like instance name is supposed to match up with the values available through the Performance Monitor MMC snap-in, which only provides _Total, and an integer index for a processor on my machine, at least when providing `"Processor"`.

If you provide `"Process"` for `CategoryName` it allows looking at a process.